# How do I run a go test using bazel with the -race option?

Tags: go, bazel

In go, I can enable the race detector for tests using the `-race` option e.g.

`go test -race ./foo/bar`

How do I do this in bazel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/pull/635, you can run bazel tests using the option `--features race` to provide the `-race` flag to go tests. e.g.

```
bazel test --features race //src/foo/bar
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `--@io_bazel_rules_go//go/config:race` ([docs](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/go/modes.rst#using-the-race-detector)) as a flag to bazel test.

`--features=race` is no longer supported and the test will warn about not being supported.

```
bazel test --@io_bazel_rules_go//go/config:race //src/foo/bar
```

Comment: Haha thanks Joe!

Comment: Do you know how to add this to a `go_test` so it's automatically included? Edit: nvm just add `race = "on"` to the rule